# How to place an arrow at the end of axis label in Gnuplot?

Tags: label, gnuplot

I would like to place an arrow at the end of the axis labels (NOT on the plot). Currently I am using dashes (---) followed by greater than symbol (>) instead. Would prefer using arrows.

Thanks

Comment: could you upload an image showing what you want to achieve? You can probably use `set arrow` http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node156.html combined with the coordinates you need : http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node49.html

Comment: Suppose I need a label say "Number" at any of the axes, I would like to place an arrow immediately after "Number<arrow>". Currently I am using "Number---->" instead.

Although I presume I have to use `set arrow` and figure the corrdinates as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer is a bit late, the easiest is probably to use the Unicode character `U+2192` →

This works even with gnuplot 4.6.0 (2012). If your arrow is too small you can enlarge it with enhanced text mode which should work at least with gnuplot>=5.0.0 (2015).

**Code:**

```
reset
set xlabel "x-label --->\nx-label →\nx-label {/:Normal=20 →}"
set ylabel "y-label --->\ny-label →\ny-label {/:Normal=20 →}"
plot x
```

**Result:**

[image]